# What is the network id in cryptonote_config.h

Tags: network

I have tried to decode it as base 58 and hexadecimal and I just can't for the life of me figure out what type of encoding it uses.

```
boost::uuids::uuid const NETWORK_ID = { {
      0x12 ,0x30, 0xF1, 0x71 , 0x61, 0x04 , 0x41, 0x61, 0x17, 0x31, 0x00, 0x82, 0x16, 0xA1, 0xA1, 0x10
} };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its contents means anything. Its role is a magic number, so you can tell whether a Levin node you connected to is running monero (and also the type of monero network: testnet, mainnet, stagenet).

Comment: What is the encoding used though?

Comment: There is none AFAIK.